# Find the missing angles in the picture containing squares and circles

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

In the following figure, $ABCD$ is a square. $\stackrel{\frown} {AB}$ and $\stackrel{\frown}{AC}$ are semicircles and quarter circles respectively. The blue circle touches $\stackrel{\frown} {AB}$ at $P$, $\stackrel{\frown} {AC}$ at $Q$ and line $BC$. $MN$ is a line such that $MN\parallel PQ$ and touches the blue circle at $R$. If $\angle MPR=\alpha$ and $\angle NQR=\beta$, find $\alpha+\beta$.

[image: Problem figure]

Here is my progress in solving the problem:

[image: Progress figure]

I could just find the radius of the blue circle. Let $OG=r$ and $AB=2$. So, $BE=1$, $BO=2-r$, $OE=1+r$, $EH=1-r$. Then, $BG^2=HO^2=4-4r$ and $4-4r+(1-r)^2=(1+r)^2$. This gives $r=\frac 12$. I can't proceed from here.

Also while creating the figures, I found the answer:

> $\alpha=45^\circ$ and $\beta=30^\circ$

So, I need a solution to the problem. All solutions are welcome, but as I'm always interested in synthetic solutions I'll most likely accept an answer with synthetic solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @MathLover pointed out in the comments, we should first prove that $PQ \parallel BC$. To show this we observe that the distance of $P$ from $BC$ is the same as the distance of $Q$ from $BC$. Indeed, the former is equal to $\frac 23 OG + \frac 13 EB = \frac 23$ and the latter equals $\frac 43 OG = \frac 23$.

Next, since $r=\frac 12$, we see that the points $M$ and $N$ lie on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.

Considering a homothety centered at $P$, we see that $B, P, R$ are collinear. Therefore
$$\angle RPM = 180^\circ - \angle MPB = \angle BAM = 45^\circ.$$

Similarly you can see that $Q,R,A$ are collinear, so
$$\angle NQR = \angle NQA = \frac 12 \angle NBA = \frac 12 \cdot 60^\circ = 30^\circ$$
where the equality $\angle NBA = 60^\circ$ follows from the observation that the triangle $ABN$ is equilateral.

Comment: Good solution but we should first show $PQ$ is parallel to $BC$, which is easy but at least that needs to be said.

Comment: @MathLover good point!

Comment: Yes that was it. Again, a nice solution. (+1)